# Using excel sheets from libnames with commas or special characters in them

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following code:

```
%macro area (ds);
data &ds (keep = areaname NSA_Tot SA_Tot);
set ms_File."&ds$"n (firsbobs = 2);
rename F2 = areaname not_seasonally_adjusted = NSA_tot seasonally_adjusted = SA_Tot;
label F2 = ' ' not_seasonally_adjusted = ' ' seasonally_adjusted = ' ';
run;
%mend area;
%area (%str(Coeur d'Alene, ID));
```

The code will not work because the dataset I have has a comma and apostrophe as part of the dataset name. So the macro doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Basically, with the code above I want the data and the set to resolve to the following:

```
data Coeur d'Alene, ID;
set ms_File."Coeur d'Alene, ID$"n (firstobs =2);
....
```

Comment: Do you have `options validmemname=extend`? What is the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 3):

To use these kinds of names, you need `options validmemname=extend;` set.  This is typically off by default.

This works:

```
options validmemname=extend;

data "Coeur d'Alene, ID"n;
  x=1;
run;

data test;
  set "Coeur d'Alene, ID"n;
run;
```

If you have `options validmemname=compat;` set, then your Excel libname engine should translate the names to valid SAS names, usually by replacing invalid characters with underscores, so this would likely work:

```
options validmemname=extend;

data test;
  set msfile.Coeur_d_Alene__ID;
run;
```

You could verify by running `proc datasets` against the libname for your file, or simply browsing it in the explorer.

Comment: I have SAS 9.2 and I i think for the options to work I need sas 9.3. 

I get the following messages when I for example call the (Akron, OH).

MLOGIC(AREA):  Beginning execution.
MLOGIC(AREA):  Parameter DS has value Akron OH
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DS resolves to Akron, OH
SYMBOLGEN:  Some characters in the above value which were subject to macro quoting have been unquoted
            for printing.
NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "DS".
1     Akron, OH

Comment: And - yes, that option is only available in 9.3+ I believe. In 9.2 you should see the other example that I post - you should have `_` and such in the member name.